# IOS: Make a messages and picture application responsive

Tags: php, ios

I am developing an picture sharing application with messages. Now want to know how to make it instant just like Viber or whatsapp. The timer of more than a minute is not a good idea the user will have to wait for a long time for the message to arrive. And HTTP request every second will have a lots of overload on the server.

I have heard about the socket programming but not sure if it is the best way. Also how to implement that?

So the question is What is the best way of implementing this kind of application?

I am using IOS and PHP as a server language.

Comment: Are you talking about a native iOS app (i.e. something you're developing in Objective-C or Swift using Xcode), or an HTML website?

Comment: I am talking about the native iOS app using Swift

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches:

- You can use your own protocol over any kind of socket you want (most probably a TCP or SSL stream), and then you need a server at the other end that keeps these connections open and send notifications on the right connections when something happens (new message...). There are probably existing frameworks for this, though all I can think of right now are more geared towards integration with web applications rather than native ones. Note that this will only work as long as you app is active in the foreground. This also means you will get as many simultaneous connections to your server as there are apps running, so you may have a scalability issue.
- or you can use Apple Push Notifications to send notifications to the app that there is something new happening. You may include all the relevant data in the payload, or you may trigger a connection by your app to fetch the rest of the data. This will work both in the background and the foreground, though slightly differently.

You may also mix both: use APNs when your app is in the background, and you own connection when it is in the foreground.

Comment: The Apple push notifications not launch the application in the background if force closed by the user. So if I use the APNs then how would my application will know that something has happened. Will the delegate method for APNs be called when the user relaunches the app?